# How to show the inclusion $M\subset\Bbb R^{k+n}$ is locally flat, where $M\subset\Bbb R^k$ is an $n$- dimensional topological manifold?

Tags: manifolds, geometric-topology

Source: Madsen & Tornehave, *From Calculus to Cohomology*

> Let $M\subset\Bbb R^k$ be an $n$-dimensional topological manifold. Show the inclusion $M\subset\Bbb R^{k+n}$ is locally flat.
>
> I.e. show that $\forall p\in M$ there exists a homeomorphism $h:U\to V$ with $p\in U$ and $U,V\subset\Bbb R^{n+k}$ open, s. t. that $h(U\cap M) = V\cap\Bbb R^n$.

I have been thinking about this for quite a while now. Especially, does anyone know what's the role of the dimension $n$ here? Since if you would change the question in the title to $M\ldots\subset\mathbb{R}^{k+j}\ldots$. where $j\in\Bbb N$ (and still $\dim M=n\;$) the statement would be false, see, e. g., the [*Alexander's horned sphere*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_horned_sphere)

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: This is not a differential topology question. This is about topological manifolds, not smooth ones. (And flatness is an algebraic tag, not a topological one.)

Comment: @TedShifrin, thank you for the remark.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $p \in M$ be a point, and $(U, \varphi)$ be a chart neighborhood in $M$, $\varphi : U \to \Bbb R^n$ being the chart homeomorphism. Considering the embedding $M \subset \Bbb R^k$, find a neighborhood $V$ of $p$ in $\Bbb R^k$ such that $V \cap M = U$ and define a continuous extension $\widetilde{\varphi} : V \to \Bbb R^n$, so that $\widetilde{\varphi}|_U = \varphi$.

Now consider the embedding $M \subset \Bbb R^k \times \{0\} \subset \Bbb R^{k+n}$ into the first factor of $\Bbb R^{k+n} = \Bbb R^k \times \Bbb R^n$ and let $B$ be a ball around $p$ in $\Bbb R^{k+n}$ such that $B \cap (\Bbb R^k \times \{0\}) = V$. Define $\Phi : B \to \Bbb R^{k+n}$ by

$$\Phi(x, y) = (\varphi^{-1}(y + \widetilde{\varphi}(x)) - x, y + \widetilde{\varphi}(x))$$

Checking that $\Phi$ is a homeomorphism onto image is a triviality. Note that for any $(x, 0) \in U \times \{0\} \subset M$, $\Phi(x, 0) = (\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(x)) - x, \varphi(x)) = (0, \varphi(x)) \in \{0\} \times \Bbb R^n$, so $\Phi(U \times \{0\}) \subset \{0\} \times \Bbb R^n$. Thus, $M \subset \Bbb R^{k+n}$ is a locally flat submanifold at $p$.

---

I've decided to make an edit to explain the idea behind the map $\Phi$. For illustration it's easier to imagine a smaller dimensional example of a non locally flat embedding than the Alexander horned sphere. I shall use a properly embedded wild arc $A \subset \Bbb R^3$. We embed $A$ horizontally in $\Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^1$.

Our plan is to shift $A \subset \Bbb R^3 \times \{0\}$ vertically up along the $\Bbb R^1$-direction in $\Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^1$ so that it "snakes upward" diagonally as we go along the arc. The natural way to do it is to observe the arc admits a homeomorphism $\varphi : A \to \Bbb R$, which we extend by Tietze extension theorem to a map $\widetilde{\varphi} : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$, and use this to construct a shear homeomorphism

$$\Phi_1 : \Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^1 \to \Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^1, \; \Phi_1(x, y) = (x, y + \widetilde{\varphi}(x))$$

The advantage of using $\varphi$ along the arc while shearing is that it "unwinds" the many twists in $A$ because $\varphi$ by definition topologically simplifies the arc to the straight real line.

$\hskip1.4in$ [image]

What was the point of this construction? The point is now $\Phi_1(A) = \{(x, \varphi(x)) : x \in A\}$ is the graph of $\varphi^{-1} : \Bbb R \to A \subset \Bbb R^3$ over the $\{0\} \times \Bbb R^1$ factor, and graphs of functions are always locally flat submanifolds. Indeed, consider a function $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ and $\Gamma_f = \{(x, f(x)) : x \in \Bbb R^n\}$ be the graph in $\Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$. Then another shear homeomorphism

$$\Phi_2 : \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m, \; \Phi_2(x, y) = (x, y - f(x))$$

satisfies $\Phi_2(\Gamma_f) \subset \Bbb R^n \times \{0\}$, making $\Gamma_f \subset \Bbb R^n \times \Bbb R^m$ locally flat.

The final homeomorphism $\Phi : \Bbb R^4 \to \Bbb R^4$ such that $\Phi(A) \subset \{0\} \times \Bbb R$, making $A$ locally flat, can be obtained from composing the  homeomorphisms $\Phi_1$ and $\Phi_2$, where $\Phi_2$ is done with the Euclidean factors reversed. None of this is special to the example I took, and one can check the formula for $\Phi$ obtained in this manner is exactly what I have above.

Comment: How do you know that such an extension $\widetilde{\varphi}$ exists?

Comment: @LordOfNumbers One way to do this is to choose a smaller closed neigbhorhood $U' \subset U$ of $p$ so that $U' = V' \cap M$ for some closed neighborhood $V'$ of $p$ in $\Bbb R^k$ and use Tietze extension theorem to obtain $\widetilde{\varphi} : V' \to \Bbb R^n$. Replace $U$ by $\text{int}(U')$ and $V$ by $\text{int}(V')$.

Comment: I have made an edit elaborating where $\Phi$ comes from anyway, in accordance with my understanding of Bill Thurston's philosophy that there should be less disparity between the way one thinks mathematics and the way one explains it (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38639/thinking-and-explaining) for an interesting discussion).

Comment: Apparently, this is known as Klee's trick.